# Steady state in CFD: Solving large and sparse linear equation of the form $Ax =b$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics, sparse-matrices

In CFD and computational physics a space can be discretized by describing it as a large amount of tiny volumes or cells. To find a steady state in the scheme, for example solving the electric field from a field of charges, one has to find an $x$ such that

$$Ax=b,$$

where $x$ represents the steady state at any of the tiny volumes and $b$ is a known quantity which may not be sparse. Hence, the length of $x$ is the enormously large amount of cells and $A$ would be so large that computationally it is **preferable to view $A$ as an operator**.

The goods news is that generally only the cells nearby interact. Therefore, $A$ is a very sparse matrix with values concentrated near the diagonal. For example $A$ could be of the form:

\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 4 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}

What is an efficient algorithm used to solve the problem given the constraints, and can it run near $O(n)$? Furthermore, is there an implementation of the algorithm in Python for example?

Comment: A decent algorithm for these types of problems is the vectorised incomplete Cholesky conjugate gradient method. This approach solves the discretised Poisson equation in $O(n^{4/3})$ average time. You can find details on this algorithm [here](https://github.com/mndxpnsn/poisson-3D/blob/master/Numerical%20solution%20of%20the%203D%20Poisson%20equation.pdf) and an implementation of this algorithm in $C$ [here](https://github.com/mndxpnsn/poisson-3D/tree/master).